# Console.log and System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine issues when 'Enable Javascript debugging for ASP.NET` is enabled

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, async-await

I've added `console.log` calls to my javascript (making an `await $.ajax` call) and `Trace.WriteLine` calls (via a `TraceKatApp` helper method) in my C# web api (the handler for the $.ajax call) and I'm confused by the order of the output.

**Javascript Code**

```js
console.log("Call " + this.options.manualResultsEndpoint);
this.options.manualResults = await $.ajax({ 
  method: "GET", 
  url: url, 
  cache: true, 
  headers: { 'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0' } 
});
console.log("Call " + this.options.manualResultsEndpoint + 
  ", COMPLETE: " + JSON.stringify(this.options.manualResults).substring( 0, 50 ) + "..." );
```

**Server C# Code**

```cs
[Route( "api/katapp/manualResults" )]
public HttpResponseMessage Handle( string key )
{
    TraceKatApp( this, $"{nameof( Handle )}: Start" );

    // code omitted for brevity
    var requestIfModified = omittedDate1;
    var lastModifiedDate = omittedDate2;

    if ( requestIfModified >= lastModifiedDate.AddMilliseconds( -lastModifiedDate.Millisecond ) )
    {
        TraceKatApp( this, $"{nameof( Handle )}: Returning StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotModified" );
        return new HttpResponseMessage { StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotModified };
    }

    // code omitted for brevity
    var httpResponse = omittedCode;

    TraceKatApp( this, $"{nameof( Handle )}: Returning httpResponse" );
    return httpResponse;
}
```

And here is my trace output in Visual Studio Output window when I have Enable javascript debugging enabled.

**Output Log**

```
Call katapp/manualResults?key=ManualResults:katapp
Call katapp/manualResults?key=ManualResults:katapp, COMPLETE: [{"@calcEngineKey":"BRD","@name":"RBLUser","@type"...
2022-11-26 07:26:51:28  Nexgen.GOLD 00060   00004   ManualResultsController /api/katapp/manualResults (CLIENT)  Handle: Start
2022-11-26 07:26:51:29  Nexgen.GOLD 00063   00003   ManualResultsController /api/katapp/manualResults (CLIENT)  Handle: Returning StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotModified
```

I'd expect the two `ManualResultsController` log entries to be inside the javascript `console.log` calls.  I tried adding a `Trace.Flush` after my `Trace.WriteLine` calls but it didn't help.

If I put a breakpoint inside the `ManualResultsController.Handle` method, then the output appears in the order I'd expect.

Is there a way to get `console.log` and `Trace.WriteLine` to 'behave' so that they appear in the exact order they were called?

Comment: _"have its own browser caching logic"_ - you mean separate to the browser's own cache?

Comment: Read the Output Log to get the gist of what I'm referring too.  I don't really know what I mean, smh.  I am totally confused on why the order isn't what I expect, unless `await $.ajax` is not behaving the way I'd expect.

Comment: Updating question.  It was a red herring.